# Facing issue while installing and running LWR LWC OSS in my windows machine

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-oss, lwr, lwr-oss

I have installed LWC OSS from the official site https://lwc.dev/

Here is the steps I followed :

1. Made sure I have node and npm installed
2. Created a lwr project : `npm init lwr@latest`
3. Installed dependancies using : `npm install`
4. Started the server : `npm run dev`

The server starts but it is not able to locate the CSS file from assets.
Whenever I run the app and render the page on browser, I receive following error in terminal

```
[
  {
    description: {
      category: 'lwrUnresolvable/asset',
      advice: [],
      message: '404: Could not find asset at "/\\public\\assets\\css\\main.css"'
    }
  }
]
```

**I will be grateful to anyone who helps me understand the problem. I have tried various things but no luck.**

Comment: To help us further, which options did you use in `npm init lwr@latest`? There are some minor differences between the options.

Comment: There are underlying issues with LWR itself on Windows, I have tried Windows Subsystem For Linux(WSL) too, but could not build a single static site having Lightning Styles and base components. Seems like it was never tested on windows.